# Calculate date difference in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, difference

Let's say we have a MYSQL database, 'employees.'

The database contains a column, "EXP," which contains a String signifying the persons START DATE... example: "2015-01-11"  (formatted: yyyy-mm-dd)

I would like for database queries to return a variable "experience" which is calculated by comparing the current date to the date contained in the EXP column.

This is the most recent attempt; what I'm trying:

```
SELECT phone, name, (DATEDIFF('CURDATE()','EXP') AS experience, bio, photo,  FROM squad
```

Can you tell what I am trying to accomplish?  If anyone knows the correct code to put here it would be greatly appreciated.

Please note, if I simply replace the code

```
(DATEDIFF('CURDATE()','EXP') AS experience
```

with 'EXP' , then there are no errors and everything works as expected.

Comment: what outcome is expected ? CURDATE() is a function, it shouldnt be quoted. and EXP is field, so keep it as it is without quote.DATEDIFF would certainly give you no of days in return, calculate your expected format at application side.

Comment: I want to move calculations to the server... I got this advice from Android Developers on youtube. :)  Thankyou for your comment.  Still nothing is working so far.

Comment: post the result of ,   <   SHOW CREATE TABLE squad;  >

Comment: mine works, tried it?

Comment: guys I'm new please dont downvote :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have extra brackets AND 'EXP' will use the string literal not the db field

```
    SELECT phone, name, DATEDIFF(now(), exp) AS experience, bio, photo
FROM squad
```

working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79e87/2

Comment: BUT.... now all results show experience = null in JSON response.... even though there is a date defined in the database.  But... you found the major problem, thankyou,

Comment: well as the demo show the mysql is correct, if you have a new question about the json, post it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question and from the select statement, I think you just have a wrong syntax check the below query

```
SELECT phone, name, DATEDIFF(now(), exp) AS experience, bio, photo
FROM squad
```

Comment: 3 open but 2 close brackets

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but I'm sorry to say that does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: @BooberBunz   can you explain your case better

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around CURDATE(), it is function, so quotes not needed

```
SELECT phone, name, (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), EXP) AS experience, bio, photo,  FROM squad
```

Comment: `'EXP'` will use the string literal not the db vale

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but I'm sorry to say that does not seem to work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT phone, name, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),EXP) AS experience, bio, photo,  FROM squad
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but I'm sorry to say that does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: `'EXP'` will use the string literal not the db vale

Comment: You are right, remove the brackets so EXP is taked as a column from your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
    SELECT 
            phone, name, 
            CONCAT( 
                    FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,exp,CURDATE())/12),
                    ' Year(s), ', 
                    (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,exp,CURDATE())%12),
                    ' Month(s)'
                  ) AS experience,
            bio, photo  
    FROM 
            squad;
```

Comment: Thanks Hytool... I figured it out now with everyone's help... the secret is:

Comment: " DATEDIFF(now(),EXP) AS experience "

Comment: yes, there was an extra bracket ! I tried to gave you diff readable format, try it if it could be in use
!